# Is there a Maf'ool مفعول in Ayah 20 of Suratul Insan?

Tags: quran, arabic

> وَإِذَا ***رَأَيۡتَ*** ثَمَّ ***رَأَيۡتَ*** نَعِيمً۬ا وَمُلۡكً۬ا كَبِيرًا (٢٠)

Is there a Maf'ool for رأيت ?  If so than where is it?

Please your sources if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two verbs in this Ayah (as you highlighted in bold). The first one is categorized as  "Lazem", i.e. a verb that does not require an object (Maf'ool). It would be translated as `if you look there you see bliss...`. The second one has its object right after it ("نعيما"), with the subject removed.